# Node.js - Reading data from Firebase after Firebase update

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I have the problem with reading data from firebase.

I'm trying this:

```
import {getDatabase, ref, child, get} from "firebase/database";
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app"
import express from "express";

const firebaseConfig = {
  ///my config
};

const app = express();

const uid = '2FDoCEItDdVLPGSmMDnwuzd8HJH182';

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());

get(child(dbRef, `users/${uid}`)).then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  } else {
    console.log("No data available");
  }
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Unfortunately, nothing is diplayed on the screen. I tried to follow this example from firebase docs:
[Firebase docs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAwC6.png)

Comment: Are you sure that "2FDoCEItDdVLPGSmMDnwuzd8HJH182" is a valid UID? Are you sure that you installed Firebase locally "firebase/database"? Is there anything displayed in the console? Probably there's. Also, try `'users/' + uid`?